# Lattice modifier causing object to scale weird

Tags: modeling, modifiers, lattice

I am using a lattice modifier but every time I use it the object scales up, does anyone know why this is? my scale is applied and it is just a basic cube. Heres is a before and after picture[image]
[image]

Comment: @moonboots that was kinda confusing, you said don't scale it in edit mode then you said do into edit mode and scale lattice vertices, what's the difference?

Comment: sorry my bad I meant when you create your lattice and scale it so that it contains your cube, scale it in Object mode, not in Edit mode. You'll go in Edit mode to deform the object. Also don't apply the scale of the lattice.

Comment: Yes, place the lattice over the object in object mode and leave all of its transform properties as they are.  Go into edit mode and move the lattice verts around to deform your object.

Comment: Ran into the same problem, kind of strange that you can't apply transform on the lattice, usally it's the otherway around. Hard find the error when you are being extra careful by applying any transforms, which is the culprit most of the time.